# pushViewController from Prototype Cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Quite simply, how do I push a new view controller from a prototype cell within a storyboard? I have a tableView reading data from a plist file, and its one default prototype cell on the storyboard.  Then, I have another view controller in the storyboard I need to link to the tapping of a cell on the table view. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Making your question some more descriptive would lead you to a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your storyboard, link your prototype table view cell to your view
   controller with a segue. Make sure to give the segue an identifier in
   its Attributes Inspector.
2. In your TableViewController class,
   implement `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`
3. In the prepareForSegue: method, get the NSIndexPath of the row the user tapped with `[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]`
4. Use the indexPath to get whatever data you need from your plist. Configure the view controller by using the `destinationViewController` property of the `UIStoryboardSegue` parameter passed into `prepareForSegue:`.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest thing would be to Ctrl-click on the prototype cell and drag the line onto the view controller that you want to transition to. It should prompt you for the type of transition—"push" transitions cause the new view controller's view to slide in from the right; "modal" transitions cause the new view to slide in from the bottom. Assuming you're using a navigation controller, the navigation bar should configure the back button automatically. You shouldn't need to write any code to achieve the behavior described in your question.